# File Association on OSX for Java Application Bundle w/o using JavaStub

Tags: java, macos, shell, launcher, info.plist

I have an OSX App-Bundle for a Java Application that does not use the Java-Stub, but a Shellscript (registered via Info.plist). I also registered my file extension in the Info.plist:

```
…
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My File Type Name</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ext1</string>
            <string>ext2</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>application/ext1</string>
            <string>application/ext2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
…
```

This is what was needed to have the LaunchService recognize my files and the association to my program.

As far as I understand the Apple Devel docs I now need to register the file open Handler in Java to have the files opened by dragging them onto the App-Icon like so (as of Java 6 update 3):

```
        Application.getApplication().setOpenFileHandler( new OpenFilesHandler() {

            @Override
            public void openFiles( OpenFilesEvent arg0 ) {
                Debug.debug( "Opening a bunch of files on osx." );
                for( File file : arg0.getFiles() ) {
                    Debug.debug( "Opening: " + file.getAbsolutePath() );
                    // Custom open action
                    FileActions.openFile( file );
                }
            }
        } );
```

My first problem is: This Handler never gets hit - there is no Debug message and the files won't open.

The second problem may be related: I can double click the associated file and the App will open if not running. Since I'm using a custom shell script to start the app I thought I'd have to add some kind of parameter or so. First this is my startscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd "$BASEDIR/../Resources/Java/"
java -Xdock:icon="../ico.icns" -Xmx256m -jar "core/myjar.jar"
```

For testing purpose I added "$1" to my arguments list - $1 is the PSN from the system … How would I connect the Event of file opening to the PSN - or is there another way to do just that (using the custom shell script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a shell script for this, AFAIK. Opened files are sent using AppleEvents, and bash does not have a way to receive those.

Comment: That does not however solve/explain the problem of dragging a file onto the file icon.

Comment: When the Finder wants to tell an application to open some files, be it via dragging, double-clicking, whatever, it sends the application an AppleEvent (a form of IPC). The application in your case is the shell script, but it does not know how to receive AppleEvents, so they just sit there unhandled. You need an executable that knows how to receive them and pass them to your Java program for processing, perhaps some sort of "Java stub".

Comment: Ok, I managed to implement the JavaApplicationStub instead of the shell script - will have to do some more changes until it's working, but the general direction seams to be fine.